# Why is only the first line printed in csv file?

Tags: c++, csv

Using the code below the output gets printed like this:

```
1     20
3     21
4     45
5     55
```

which is correct,
but, while printing it in a csv file it gets printed like this(below) even though codes for printing and writing in csv file are inside the same brackets(same place),

```
1     20
```

which means only the first line is printed. Why is it not printing the remaining other lines in the csv file ?  Is there any difference between printing the output and writing it in a csv file in c++ ?

This is the block of code :

```
ofstream outfile;
double average = (((double) total) / num);
cout << lFraction << " , " << arraySize << " " << average << endl;
outfile.open("results1.csv");
outfile << arraySize << " , " << average << endl ;
outfile.close();
```

Comment: Looks like you're only writing one line. Recommend adding more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you open the file that deletes the existing contents of the file.

You have two options:

- Open the file once, write *all* the results, and then close it.
- Use the `app`end flag so that the file contents aren't deleted and new data is written at the end: `outfile.open("results1.csv", ios::app);`

The first option is recommended because constantly opening and closing the same file wastes time.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I was looking for, problem solved.